# DeepXDE error - NotImplementedError: Unsupported backend: torch

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, tensorflow2.0, jax

i'm keep getting the following error saying i chose 'torch' as a backend and it is not supported.

the error:

"
NotImplementedError: Unsupported backend: torch.
Please select backend from tensorflow.compat.v1, tensorflow, pytorch, jax or paddle.
"

my code snippet :

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import deepxde as dde
from deepxde.backend import set_default_backend
set_default_backend("tensorflow")
```

i changed the backend to "tensorflow" and also tried "paddle" and "jax", but keep getting same error.
i uninstalled all python and re-installed them. i tried creating new environments and installing all libraries from scratch. i cannot get rid of this error.
i tried on a different computer and it runs ok without issues, but i want to run on this computer since it has GPU.
please assist ...

Comment: typo. "torch" vs "pytorch".